# Python follow redirects and then download the page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have the following python script and it works beautifully.

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://abc.com' # write the url here

usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()

print data
```

however, some of the URL's I give it may redirect it 2 or more times. How can I have python wait for redirects to complete before loading the data. 
For instance when using the above code with

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=KEYWORD&btnI=1
```

which is the equvilant of hitting the im lucky button on a google search, I get:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=KEYWORD&btnI=1'
>>> usick = urllib2.urlopen(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
>>>
```

Ive tried the (url, data, timeout) however, I am unsure what to put there.

EDIT:
I actually found out if I dont redirect and just used the header of the first link, I can grab the location of the next redirect and use that as my final link

Comment: are you familiar with `HTTPRedirectHandler`

Comment: I was not. Just googled it. I can see how to make it NOT follow. However, I can not force it TO follow

Comment: I know it's been a while, but can you dig deep in the memory vault and tell me how you solved this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might be better off with Requests library which has better APIs for controlling redirect handling:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Requests:

https://pypi.org/project/requests/ (urllib replacement for humans)

Comment: @user1048138: Would you mind telling us what you did find to solve your problem?

Comment: That feature just BLEW my mind. Also, it's important to note for other requests (like HEAD), you must set allow_redirects to True for this to work.

Comment: While the pointer is correct, this does not immediately address the issue discussed.

Answer (score 33):

Use `requests` as the other answer states, here is an example. The redirect will be in `r.url`. In the example below the `http` is redirected to `https`

For HEAD:

```py
In [1]: import requests
   ...: r = requests.head('http://github.com', allow_redirects=True)
   ...: r.url

Out[1]: 'https://github.com/'
```

For GET:

```py
In [1]: import requests
   ...: r = requests.get('http://github.com')
   ...: r.url

Out[1]: 'https://github.com/'
```

Note for HEAD you have to specify `allow_redirects`, if you don't you can get it in the headers but this is not advised.

```py
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.head('http://github.com')

In [3]: r.headers.get('location')
Out[3]: 'https://github.com/'
```

To **download the page** you will need GET, you can then access the page using `r.content`

Comment: Why is getting it by the header not advised?

Comment: I know this wasn't that long ago but it feels like it, I think I did a validation and found it to not be as reliable, it might also say that in the docs. If you do a validation let me know what you find.