# Follow HTML or PHP redirects with Python?

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I want to see the last URL of the website with Python. I'm mostly using `requests` and `urllib2`, but everything is welcome.

The website I'm trying isn't giving **`Response 302`**. It directly redirects using HTML or maybe PHP.

I used `requests` module for this, but it seems like it doesn't count HTML PHP redirects as "Redirect".

My current code:

```py
def get_real(domain):
    red_domain = requests.get(domain, allow_redirects=True).url
    return red_domain

print(get_real("some_url"))
```

If there is a way to achieve this, how? Thanks in advance!

---

### Posts I checked:

- [Python follow redirects and then download the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827545/python-follow-redirects-and-then-download-the-page)
- [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url/20475639)
- [Tracking redirection of the request using request history | Packtpub](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781784395414/1/ch01lvl1sec18/tracking-redirection-of-the-request-using-request-history)

---

**EDIT:** URL I'm trying: http://001.az. It's using HTML to redirect.

***HTML Code inside it:***

```html
<HTML> <HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; url=http://fm.vc"></HEAD> </HTML>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Sure, I forgot to share it. Now, I'm editing question.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that? Yes, of course. Is there a simple way? Unfortunately no. You will have to mimic what a browser would do, meaning parse the page searching the HEADER bloc for a META tag having attribute HTTP-EQUIV with value Refresh. BeautifulSoup could help here, else you will have to use a stock xml/html parser and pray for the HTML to be correct. Please say if BeautifulSoup is an option here.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta! Yes, we can use `BeautifulSoup` and/or `xml/html parser`.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup can help in detecting HTML Meta redirections:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# use request to extract the HTML text
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.lower(), "html5lib")  # lower because we only want redirections

try:
    content = soup.heap.find('meta', {'http-equiv': 'refresh'}).attrs['content']
    ix = content.index('url=')
    url = content[ix+4:]
    # ok, we have to redirect to url
except AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError:
    url = None

# if url is not None, loop going there...
```